# Flutter / Android PDF viewer is low quality

Tags: flutter, pdf, view, native

I am making a flutter app to view PDF files.

I have tried a bunch of different packages (native_pdf_view, flutter_cached_pdfview, uc_pdfview), and it seems like they all result in a somewhat low-quality render.

When I look at the same file using Google Drive's PDF Viewer, the quality is significantly improved. Is there an antialiasing setting I'm missing somewhere that would improve the PDF rendering performance?

Zoomed in screenshot showing the poor antialiasing with native_pdf_view:
[image: PDF quality with native_pdf_view]

Zoomed in screenshot showing the same file using Google Drive:
[image: PDF quality with Google Drive]

Any advice on how to improve the rendering of the PDF would be much appreciated. The relevant section of code for the PdfView widget is below. (If I increase the 'width' and 'height' parameters, the quality looks slightly better, but still nowhere near the quality of Google Drive, yet soon runs out of memory)

```
PdfView(
                documentLoader: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                pageLoader: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                controller: _pdfController,
                renderer: (PdfPage page) => page.render(
                  width: page.width * 2,
                  height: page.height * 2,
                  format: PdfPageFormat.JPEG,
                  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                ),
              ))
```

Edit: Here is the source PDF file used in these screenshots (although other music PDF files also show the same lower quality rendering):
https://www.free-scores.com/PDF_EN/chopin-frederic-prelude-15-296.pdf

This PDF uses a font to display the music ( https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/the-feta-font ).

Comment: I've tried .JPEG, .PNG, and .WEBM (the three options exposed through the native_pdf_viewer library); none of them seem to have any affect on the resulting image quality. Changing the *2 to *1 makes it look even blockier. I don't think there are any other settings for changing DPI - just the width/height (which, presumably then scales the image down to fit the screen)

Comment: Both screenshots were taken on the device, and it works without an internet connection, meaning the Google Drive app is rendering a nicer image on the device (and not server-side). This PDF uses a font (https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/the-feta-font) so yes, it is a vector image. I guess to clarify, my question is how can I increase the rendering quality in Flutter? Even if I can't use the native_pdf_render package and need to render & display images from the PDF more manually, it would be nice to know there's a way to display a PDF file in higher quality.

Comment: When I increase the height/width multiplier in native_pdf_view, presumably that generates an image with greater resolution. However, it still doesn't look nearly as crisp as Google Drive on the same device. This may be more of a question for the native_pdf_view developer, to see if there are any additional settings they could expose into Android PDF renderer that would fix this. Or, alternatively, any scaling options that could be exposed to scale the image down more nicely so it doesn't look as blocky when zoomed out.

Comment: I have the same issue with native_pdf_view. I tried also : width: page.width * 2 and height: page.height * 2, but no improvement detected. I succeed let me know thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to resolve the problem of low quality by increasing the `width` and the `height` attributes in `page.render` and by giving `quality` a value of `100`. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
renderer: (PdfPage page) => page.render(
          width: page.width * 5,
          height: page.height * 5,
          format: PdfPageImageFormat.jpeg,
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
          quality: 100,
        ),
```

**Note:** use the last version of the `native_pdf_view` package because `format: PdfPageFormat` is no longer supported. Now it uses `PdfPageImageFormat` instead of `PdfPageFormat`.